# ImageMagick get pixel color by x y coordinates

Tags: imagemagick

I have this 30x20 image which is 10x increased in size here:

[image]

I need to get the color of the pixel with the coordinates `x 19` and `y 14` which in this case is red

I changed all kind of values in this code:

```
-crop "1x1+0+%[fx:h-7]+0" -format "%[hex:u.p{0,0}]\n" info:
```

but only get the blue pixel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want pixel at (19,14), you need:

```
magick image.png -format "%[hex:u.p{19,14}]\n" info:
```

Or:

```
magick image.png -crop 1x1+19+14 -format "%[hex:u.p{0,0}]\n" info:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with %[pixel:u.p{x,y}] in Imagemagick. So for you zoomed image:

```
convert img.png -format "%[pixel:u.p{185,134}]\n" info:
```

srgb(255,0,0)

and for your **original image:**

```
convert img.png -format "%[pixel:u.p{19,14}]\n" info:
```

Comment: Thank you too! Mark was slightly faster so I checked his answer. I upvoted yours though

Comment: My answer gives rgb values. Mark's gives hex values. For one pixel, I would not expect any difference other than what else is going on in your computer at the very same time. But thanks for the upvote.